# Show Discord live member count, online member, voice chat member count and server boost count on my Website

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, discord

I have a Discord server and am currently creating a website for it.

I want to show live stats from my server on an html page (Member: 10, Online: 5, Voice Chat: 3, Server boost: 10) like this.

Currently I have the code below, however I get nothing back. There are no numbers on the page.

I don't understand the fetch point exactly.

Which url do I need to fetch to get the correct data?

HTML:

```
   <div class="right-info">
     <ul>
       <li>
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i><div id="membercount"></div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i><div id="onlineusers"></div>
       </li>
       <li><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
         <div id="vcusers"></div> 10
       </li>
       <li>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-gift"></i><div id="serverboosts"></div> 15
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

````
            fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/1038123472007737375/widget.json`)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data)

                    document.getElementById('membercount').innerHTML = data[0]['membercount'];
                    document.getElementById('serverboosts').innerHTML = data[0]['serverboosts'];
                    document.getElementById('vcusers').innerHTML = data[0]['vcusers'];
                    document.getElementById('onlineusers').innerHTML = data[0]['onlineusers'];
                })
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            updatePage(window.location.href);
        }, 1000);```
````

Comment: You have to authenticate yourself, and use the base API from Discord.  Then you will probably able to attach queries to your endpoint URL and look for the data in their JSON, such as (member count, users, etc..) Here's the official documentation how you can use their API.
https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication

Comment: I tried it but dont get it, do you have an example of the god api url?

Comment: If I were approaching this task, I would have a backend that either connects to discord api for gathering this information so you can hide your authentication credentials, or have a database that is updated periodically and fetch the data from that database. I'm not familiar with discord api / bot services though.